# how to avoid duplicate upload in php?

Tags: php, ftp, upload

i used from function crop_compress() to crop and compress image and then upload them

```
function crop_compress($source_url,$target_file,$qual) {

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$thumb_width = $width;
$thumb_height = (9/16)*$width;
.
.
.
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );
imagejpeg($thumb , $target_file,$qual);
return $target_file;}

$filename= 'crop_compress($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$key],$target_fileL,90)'
```

and it work fine.
now i want to upload this image with ftp and use ftp_put:

```
ftp_put($connecti,$target_file, $filename,  FTP_BINARY);
```

and it work fine too, but it upload 2 times that i dont want.
one image in my directory and one with ftp

my question is how to avoid upload in my directory?
i know that ftp_put() and crop_compress() upload separately but i dont know which one should come first and how create a tmp_file to source in another or something else to avoid this problem?!

more info:

```
$target_dirL = "user"; #in the main host
$tempL=explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$key]);
$target_fileL = $target_dir .$username1. '.' . end($tempL);

$target_dir = "user/$username/"; #another host
$temp=explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$key]);
$target_file = $target_dir .$username1. '.' . end($temp);

$connecti = ftp_connect($anotherHost) or die('Couldn\'t connect to ftp server');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `unlink( $filename );` after `ftp_put($connecti,$target_file, $filename,  FTP_BINARY);`

This will delete the file after it had been uploaded via FTP.

Comment: i think about it but there is not a way to avoid upload at first?

Comment: @hameds1 what do you mean? I don't understand what you mean by avoiding the upload. Please explain better.

Comment: this code upload image in two location. one in root directory of main host and another to ftp host. i want upload only with ftp in ftp host

Comment: @hameds1 please show the code for `$connecti,$target_file, $filename`